# yarn global install isn't available in path

Tags: ubuntu, npm, yarnpkg, nvm

I'm trying to install yarn on Ubuntu 18.04 using nvm and npm. The installation succeeds and shows that it's installed globally. The `which` command points to the right directory as well, but the command can't be used by itself, or as `yarn install` because the system tries to use `/usr/bin/yarn` instead.

```
$ nvm which current
/home/[user]/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/node

$ npm install -g yarn@1.16.0

$ which yarn
/home/[user]/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/yarn

$ yarn
bash: /usr/bin/yarn: No such file or directory

$ echo $PATH
/home/[user]/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin:/home/[user]/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/[user]/bin:...
```

Answer (score 12):

It turns out the fix is to close the terminal and reopen a new terminal window.